# BadCredentialsException Symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm working on updating an existing project from 2.0.1 to 2.8.3. I know its a big jump but I have a lot of it working.

I can't seem to get the FOS user bundle to work right though. Whenever I type in a correct username/password I get a BadCredentialsException, with the message: "Bad credentials."

Here is my security.yml

```
security:

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            form_login:
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
                #success_handler: authentication_handler
                #failure_handler: authentication_handler
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                remember_me:  true
            anonymous: ~

            # http_basic: ~

        # form_login: ~
```

Thoughts? Opinions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to change the password of an user through the command `php app/console fos:user:change-password [username] [new password]` then authenticate it ? I suspect it's a password encoding problem.

Comment: I had copied over the wrong config when I went to update the app. Thanks for your help!